# exact word replacement using arrays

Tags: php

I have an array of values and links and need to replace the exact value in the content with the link only once.
For this preg_replace can help like:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [keyword] => this week [links] => http://google.com ) 
[1] => Array ( [keyword] =>this [links] => http://yahoo.com ) 
[2] => Array ( [keyword] => week [links]=> http://this-week.com ) ) 
)
```

The text is:

```
$content = "**This week** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **week** will be better. **This** is a kind of great news.**This week** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **week** will be better. **This** is a kind of great news.**This week** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **week** will be better. **This** is a kind of great news.";
```

I tried to do with string replace - as arrays can be used for string replacement, but then all the occurences are replaced.
I tried to use substr_replace, with position, but it is not working as I'd like to be.

```
$pos = strpos($content,$keyword);
if($pos !== false){
    substr_replace($content,$link,$pos,strlen($keyword));
}
```

and preg_replace, with looping array:

```
preg_replace('/'.$keyword.'/i', $link, ($content),1);
```

it is kind of working, it replaces only once the keyword with link, but if the keyword is compound (**this week**), it is replaced with **this** and **week**, which is wrong ...

Would appreciate your help ... thanks.

**Update**

$link is the issue - if it is without 'http://' works fine ... 
Now this is under question, how to escape it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you would use instead of links some kind of 'ID', use it in preg_replace and when this is done, you can call str_replace and replace IDs with real links?

```
$content = preg_replace('/'.$keyword.'/i', $IDS, ($content),1);
$content = str_replace($IDS, $link, $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I write sample of code that replaces all of your values. I don't know what you want exactly the text to be replaced with so I put sample text

```
 $content = "**This week** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **week** will be better. **This** is a kind of great news.**This week** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **week** will be better. **This** is a kind of great news.**This week** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **week** will be better. **This** is a kind of great news.";
 $replacement = array('[linkthiswWeek]', '[links_this]','[links_Week]');
 $patterns = array('/This week/', '/This/', '/week/');
 echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacement, $content);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
**[linkthiswWeek]** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **[links_Week]** will be better. **[links_this]** is a kind of great news.**[linkthiswWeek]** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **[links_Week]** will be better. **[links_this]** is a kind of great news.**[linkthiswWeek]** I'd like to go to the seaside, but the weather is not good enough. Next **[links_Week]** will be better. **[links_this]** is a kind of great news.
```

You can fit replacement to your needs by modifing `$replacement` array

Comment: thanks, Robert ... I tested your example and works ok, but if I implement this in my code it does not :( it replaces 'this week' with link for 'this' and 'week' .. I tried to make arrays manually, not calling from DB, but does not help ... really not sure what can be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Robert's answer works but replaces every occurence, which was not required. Adding ', 1' to the end of the preg replace replaces each occurence only once.

e.g. echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacement, $content, 1);

Comment: yes, Robert's answer works - but not in my code ... and I implemented the same arrays, but replaces each word separatelly - in fact I was trying to do this before ... maybe is something wrong with content - that breaks the replacement - can be, and what ..hm. if I add another keyword, shorter, but similar, let's say 'thi' and link 'thi.com', it replaces 'this' with the last add.

Comment: Roberts code works because he is using 2 array, one for what you are searching for, and one of what to replace it with. I think your araay of array is to complicated for what you are trying to acheive. Also we are talking string substitution here so the search fields and replacements should be strings.

Comment: ok, I'm using simple examples .. I'm testing so many hours and I can't figure out what is going on. Now was working on LoremIpsum text, works ok, but on my text - simple one, with simple arrays, built on the exact same way manually, does NOT work ... it drives me crazy :(